# ffmpeg: make movie from images set with partial filename stamp overlay (date-time)

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have two cameras in my garden taking time-lapse jpeg images of two plants that interest me.

One of those already has overlay time-stamp and it doesn't give me problems, I make a daily movie with:

```
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -y -f image2pipe -i - -an -threads 4  -vcodec libx264 -s vga -r 24 -b:v 512k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method hex -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -bf 3 -b-pyramid 1 -8x8dct 1 -coder 1 -me_range 16 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -loglevel info "../video_test.mp4"
```

And the movie comes out perfect, with the images in perfect sequence.

As to the other, the method I'm using is a two-step, that I would like to convert to one-step. It takes every picture, makes an overlay on each one, stores in a tmp folder from where the script above makes the film.

It works but is very time consuming and quality degrading due to the double encoding process.

So, I decided to make it a one step with either of the scripts below:

```
cat *.jpg | ffmpeg -y -f image2pipe -i - -an -threads 4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf: text="Partial filename of each image, containing date-time": fontcolor=yellow@0.8: x=7: y=7" -vcodec libx264 -s vga -r 24 -b:v 512k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method hex -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -bf 3 -b-pyramid 1 -8x8dct 1 -coder 1 -me_range 16 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -loglevel info "../video_test.mp4"
```

**Question 1:** This works but I can't get the filename being processed to insert it in the filter.

There would be another way:

```
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec TEST=$'{}' \; -exec cat {} \; | ffmpeg -y -f image2pipe -i - -an -threads 4 -vf "drawtext=fontfile=/usr/share/fonts/dejavu/DejaVuSans.ttf: text=$TEST: fontcolor=yellow@0.8: x=7: y=7" -vcodec libx264 -s vga -r 24 -b:v 512k -flags +loop+mv4 -cmp 256 -partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8 -me_method hex -subq 7 -trellis 1 -refs 5 -bf 3 -b-pyramid 1 -8x8dct 1 -coder 1 -me_range 16 -g 250 -keyint_min 25 -sc_threshold 40 -i_qfactor 0.71 -qmin 10 -qmax 51 -qdiff 4 -loglevel info "../video_test.mp4"
```

As you can see, the intention is getting the filename in variable, process it, and use it in the filter.

**Question 2** There are two problems here. The first is the images not being sorted by filename so, out of timing.
The second is 'find' is not working as I expected with two exec commands.

So, this was rather extense, I hope you could read it all. Is there anyone able to help, please?

TIA
jss

Comment: Since a piped input won't convey its filename, you will have to use a different approach. Basic idea is to create a SRT subtitles file, where each subtitle entry is the part of the filename you want to stamp and its time in/out points sync to a single frame. Use the subtitles filter to apply it.

Comment: Thank you for the good tip. Yes, that might work although a bit elaborated.

Comment: It would be much easier if the drawtext filter would give out the filename of the image being processed as, for instance, metadata. If it can give out the ordinal number of the image, why not its filename? In the meanwhile, I was thinking of taking another approach, by building a text file with all the filenames, sort and process, and feed each image in turn to ffmpeg, putting the image text in a variable that drawtext would pull. I just have to keep the pipe open during the loop, do you think it would work?

Comment: *If it can give out the ordinal number of the image* --> it can't. All filters keep a count of the frames fed to them. And if frames from the input were dropped beforehand, the filter can't account for them in its count.

Comment: Are you planning to run `n` ffmpeg commands in series for `n` images?

Comment: In the case of the index file containing the filenames, no, I was planning to keep the pipe "| ffmpeg - f image2pipe ... -i - out.mp4" open during the loop "for i in *.jpg; do FILENAME=xxx; done; cat...". I didn't test this yet, even built it.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know FFmpeg, and I don’t have it, so I can’t test this. 
But you say `cat *.jpg` (and, for example, `echo *.jpg`)
give you the files in the correct order. 
In that case, you should be able to do what you want with

```
for f in *.jpg
do
   ffmpeg -y … args … text="$f": … more args … -loglevel info "../video_test.mp4" < "$f"
done
```

or, if you insist on using `cat`:

```
for f in *.jpg
do
   cat "$f" | ffmpeg -y … args … text="$f": … more args … -loglevel info "../video_test.mp4"
done
```

Comment: I think that wouldn't work because you would open one ffmpeg thread for each image and you would end up with as many movies as images, all one frame long. Anyway, I already solved the question using a tip in a comment of the op. Just building a srt format file, containing all the overlays I want with the proper timing, and then cat ffmpeg with the "subtitle" filter. And yes, you are right, cat sorts the files.